# TF30167 Error trying to create new team project in VS 11 and TFS 11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

When trying to create a new team project with any of the default project templates I get error TF30167.  Looking at the project creation log it looks to be a schema validation error in the autogenerated processtemplate.xml file.  The exact schema validation error is:

> The element 'metadata' has invalid child element 'version'. List of possible elements expected: 'plugins'

Here's my environment:

TFS 11- Windows Server 8 consumer preview VM
VS 11 - Windows 7 enterprise x86

Both computers are in a workgroup and I've added the TFS 11 Windows installed administrator account to the TFS Administrator Console Users and the default project collection.  I'm able to connect to the TFS 11 server using the TFS11 server's administrator account.  Finally, I've installed successfully all components of TFS 11 except I skipped the sharepoint component.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing the team explorer for ms visual studio 11.  After installing this the default process templates no longer create a schema validation.  My guess is that the default visual studio 11 install has the basic version of the team explorer that doesn't have the updates for TFS 11.